How is it conceptually possible to have fault-tolerant quantum computing with constant overhead
The quantum threshold theorem guarantees that if a circuit is composed of $N_L$ logical gates, then by implementing error-correction it is possible to asymptotically remove the noise with a number of physical qubits (resp gates) per logical qubits (resp gates) that is a polylog function of $N_L$.
I have heard that good quantum LDPC code allow to "surpass" the quantum threshold theorem and can do a constant overhead. See, e.g. this paper.
I don't understand how this is conceptually possible. If I assume a rectangular circuit composed of $Q_L$ logical qubits and of depth $D_L$, clearly, if I increase the depth while keeping $Q_L$ constant, I need to protect more my information hence add physical qubits per logical ones. The overhead as a function of $N_L=D_L \times Q_L$ will not be constant.
I suppose "constant overhead" is therefore a matter of terminology.
My questions are then:

What does constant overhead means in this context?
What happens if I increase $D_L$ while keeping $Q_L$ fixed in terms of number of physical/logical qubits.

I suspect it is constant overhead in physical/logical qubit as a function of $Q_L$ for $D_L$ kept fixed, but I'm unsure.

It may be helpful if you could explain the context or provide a source for the claim, for instance, you may be referring to this paper with the same title. Here, "overhead" just refers to the ratio of physical qubits to logical qubits

I believe in the original Gottesman paper he assumes the length of the computation is bounded by some (polynomial?) function of the space. So he was in a regime where you aren’t free to arbitrarily increase the depth.

@JahanClaes would you say that my intuition in the comment below Craig answer is the good one? I guess it is somehow related to what you say? Essentially that if depth gets longer, of course you need to add physical/logical qubits but for good codes doing so will also add logical qubits.

What constant overhead means in this context have been clarified, but I will try to conceptually explain how it is possible.
The main result of the linked paper is Theorem 1, which states that for specific families of stabilizer codes with good properties, you can fault-tolerantly simulate some circuits with $Q$ qubits and $N$ error locations (ie state preparations, gates, qubit measurements) using $\tilde{Q}=\mathcal{O}(Q)$ physical qubits and $\tilde{N}\approx\mathcal{O}(N\mathrm{poly}(Q))$ physical locations.
It is therefore a constant overhead in space and at worse a polynomial overhead in time.
The details are somewhat intricate and hard to faithfully summarize. What I personally gather from it is the following:
It applies to some quantum LDPC code families

Each $[n_i, k_i, d_i]$ member of the family must abide by the same LDPC constraints.
The family must have a non-vanishing encoding rate $\left(\frac{k_i}{n_i}\underset{i\to\infty}{\to} R\right)$.
The family must be populated enough (the $n_i$s must scale properly).
Each member suppresses errors well enough and an error correction round has a logical error rate of $\mathcal{O}\left(1/g(n_i)\right)$ for some function $g$. I think that $g$ generalizes the notion of distance and $g\approx\exp(d_i)$ in the simplest cases.
An efficient decoding algorithm must be available for this code family (otherwise the result is of little practical interest, we might as well directly simulate the circuit on a classical computer).

The choice of code family limits which circuits can be simulated

The size of the simulated circuit must grow slower than $g$ (ie $N(Q)\approx o(g(Q))$).
Code families that correct errors exponentially will be able to simulate polynomially-sized circuits.
Code families that correct errors polynomially can simulate circuits with $N(Q)$ polynomially growing with a smaller degree.
The circuit must be wide enough ($Q$ must be above some value).

Syndrome extraction can be performed with cat states

Measurements involving encoded copies of the code (e.g. Steane syndrome extraction) would be too costly.
At each syndrome extraction step (at worst once for each gate in the circuit), each stabilizer is repeatedly measured (at most a polynomial number of times).
LDPC property tells you that syndrome extraction induces a constant overhead in space. It induces at worst a polynomial overhead in time, depending on the number of repetitions.
Naive syndrome extraction might however be sufficient since errors can only be spread to a constant number of qubits for LDPC codes.

Logical qubits are stored in several codeblocks

Computation is not performed in one big $[\tilde{Q},Q]$ code but distributed across multiple smaller members of code family.
The size $k^{\prime}$ of these codes must be large enough to not undermine the overall error suppression capability, but small enough so that the overhead of fault-tolerantly acting on them is sublinear in $Q$.
It explains the need of a well-populated code family.

Logical operations are performed fault-tolerantly through gate teleportation

Logical operations are performed via stabilizer/magic states teleportation (see this paper, IV and V).
These states are prepared fault-tolerantly on some concatenated codes of size $k^{\prime}$, with a polylogarithmic overhead in $k^{\prime}$ and therefore overall sublinear in $Q$.

If all these conditions are fulfilled, a threshold below which the computation can be run with desired precision can be derived.
The assumptions of this theorem are tailored in order to be able to find $k^{\prime}$ so that the fault-tolerance overhead can be distributed across small enough code instances that these overheads sum up to a linear increase in the number of qubits used, thus leading to a constant space overhead.
Several code families meeting these assumptions (including the efficient decoding algorithm) have been found, see for examples here or here.

That's a really great answer, thanks!

It's worth noting that code families with efficient decoders have since been constructed: e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.03821 and https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.12470 .
Syndrome extraction with cat states is also not necessary. It suffices to do the naive syndrome extraction circuit if the code is LDPC -- any single error will propagate to constant number of other locations

Pet peeve: you're talking about constant spatial overhead, not constant overhead, since for a computation the time overhead is a relevant kind of overhead.
I would imagine that a paper claiming a constant spatial overhead computation would require that the execution time is polynomial in the number of qubits. They would then prove the level of protection increases exponentially versus the number of qubits, and this would cover the slower-growing time overhead. But each paper may have a different version of this.

Is the intuition that when the computation gets longer, for sure you need to add physical qubit to increase the code distance and protect better. However with good codes you can increase the code distance and the number of logical qubits "at the same time", allowing to increase the level of protection of each logical gate, while increasing the width of the algorithm. Therefore it would provide an overall constant overhead.

Yes. The extra error correction comes from the extra breathing room of being able to use larger block size on larger problems.
